# How to index number of specific DIV simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

how would i get index number of `div class="age"` using simple html dom?

```
         <div class="main">   
          <div id="names">
             <div class="name">...</div>
             <div class="subject">...</div>
             <div class="class">...</div>
             <div class="age">...</div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I feel like there needs to be a 'not-jquery' tag for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('names');
var c = parent.children;

for (var i=0; i< c.length; i++) 
  if (c[i].classList.contains('age'))
    console.log('Found at index '+ i);
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="names">
    <div class="name">...</div>
    <div class="subject">...</div>
    <div class="class">...</div>
    <div class="age">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#names div').index($('#names > .age'))
```

This will get the index of the `div class="age"` starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

if you want the index of `div class="age"` in the `div class="name"` then this should work fine.

```
console.log($(".age").index());
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple-html-dom you need to jump through some hoops:

```
$el = $html->find('.age', 0);
$i = 0; // start at 0
while($el = $el->previousSibling()) $i++;
echo $i; // 3
```

Comment: `$el = $html->find('.age', 0);` in 0 it shouldn't be `$i` or i misunderstand your idea??

Comment: no, in that case it means: the first `.age` element.